# Popup copied from one Google Doc Doesn't Popup when Copied

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm prompting a user for information in a google doc via the Script Editor, and I've gotten it to work in a test document, but when I try to copy it over to another it doesn't pop up.The first one didn't require a developer key to work, although I set it up in my Google Cloud Platform console as part of troubleshooting. It's supposed to push a popup form when the user opens the google doc, but in the second document nothing shows up unless you hit Run. The user should not be accessing the Script Editor, so this is not ideal.

Any ideas on why this is happening? Thanks in advance

```js
function onOpen() {
  showPicker();
}

var VALUE;

function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("login.html");
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, " ");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-145078782-1"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
    
      gtag('config', 'UA-145078782-1');
    </script>
    <style>
      header {
        background: black;
        padding: 10px 20px;
      }
      header h1, header a {
        margin: 0px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
      }

      body {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          background-size: cover;
          font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        
        .box {
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          width: 25rem;
          padding: 2.5rem;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          border: 1px solid #dadce0;
          -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
          border-radius: 8px;

        }
        
        .box h2 {
          margin: 0px 0 -0.125rem;
          padding: 0;
          color: #fff;
          text-align: center;
          color: #202124;
          font-family: 'Google Sans','Noto Sans Myanmar UI',arial,sans-serif;
          font-size: 24px;
          font-weight: 400;
        }

        .box p {
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 400;
          letter-spacing: .1px;
          line-height: 1.5;
          margin-bottom: 25px;
          text-align: center;
        }
        
        .box .inputBox {
          position: relative;
        }
        
        .box .inputBox input {
          width: 93%;
          padding: 0.625rem 10px;
          font-size: 1rem;
          letter-spacing: 0.062rem;
          margin-bottom: 1.875rem;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          background: transparent;
          border-radius: 4px;
          
        }
        
        .box .inputBox label {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 10px;
          padding: 0.625rem 0;
          font-size: 1rem;
          color: grey;
          pointer-events: none;
          transition: 0.5s;
        }
        
        .box .inputBox input:focus ~ label,
        .box .inputBox input:valid ~ label,
        .box .inputBox input:not([value=""]) ~ label {
          top: -1.125rem;
          left: 10px;
          color: #1a73e8;
          font-size: 0.75rem;
          background-color: white;
          height: 10px;
          padding-left: 5px;
          padding-right: 5px;
        }
        .box .inputBox input:focus {
          outline: none;
          border: 2px solid #1a73e8;
        }
        .box input[type="submit"] {
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #1a73e8;
          padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem;
          cursor: pointer;
          border-radius: 0.312rem;
          font-size: 1rem;
          float: right;
        }
        
        .box input[type="submit"]:hover {
          background-color: #287ae6;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(66,133,244,0.45), 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(66,133,244,0.3);
        }
        .popup-without-close .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-button.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  display: none;
}
    </style>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>
      function SubForm() {
        $.ajax({
          url:'https://api.apispreadsheets.com/data/10050/',
          type:'post',
          data:$("#myForm").serializeArray()
        });
        closeDialog();
      }
      var x = document.getElementById("myForm");
      function closeDialog() {
        x.closeDialog();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Sign in</h2>
      <p>Use your Provided Credentials</p>
      <form id="myForm">
        <div class="inputBox">
          <input type="email" name="email" required onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);"  value="">
          <label>Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="inputBox">
              <input type="text" name="password" required onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="">
              <label>Password</label>
            </div>
        <button onclick="SubForm()" id="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello! Would be happy to help but without seeing the script and having more information on how you have it set up, there is not much to go on I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

### It looks like you need an [Installed trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

In a nutshell, simple triggers, like using `onOpen` without installing it, can be copied with the sheet and it will work "out the box". However, they are very restricted and so, this is why it won't have access to the UI, i.e. a popup.

To install the trigger on the new sheet, you need to open the script editor. Once you are at the editing screen, to the left, click on the triggers icon.

[image]

Once there, you can:

[image]

It will ask you what function you want to run when the trigger is triggered, and what type of trigger you want it to be (choose onOpen) - then it will likely ask for authorization, which you should grant.

#### For more details:

- [Simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: that fixed it! Thanks so much :)